# Keras Lambda layer, how to use multiple arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have this function:

```
def sampling(x):
    zeros = x*0
    samples = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log(x), 1)
    samples = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(samples, depth=2), axis=1)
    return zeros+samples
```

That I call from this layer:

```
x = layers.Lambda(sampling, name="lambda")(x)
```

But I need to change the *depth* variable in the *sampling* function, so I would need something like this:

```
def sampling(x, depth):
```

But, how can I make it work with the Lambda layer ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda function inside the Lambda layer...

```
def sampling(x, depth):
    zeros = x*0
    samples = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log(x), 1)
    samples = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(samples, depth=depth), axis=1)
    return zeros+samples
```

usage:

```
Lambda(lambda t: sampling(t, depth=3), name="lambda")(x)
```